# How can I use the 'no-map' property of reserved-memory in device tree? Still accessed with virtual address

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I have this device tree.

```
   reserved-memory {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        ranges;

        axpu_reserved_mem: axpursvd@90000000 {
            no-map;
            reg = <0x0 0x90000000 0x0 0x30000000>;
        };
    };

    axpu@50000000 {
        compatible = "ab21-axpu";
        reg = <0 0x50000000 0 0x10000000>;
         ...
        memory-region = <&axpu_reserved_mem>;
    };
```

With simple test, in the probe function, I did something like this (reduced).

```c
struct axpu_dev {
    struct device *dev;
    void __iomem *base;
    u64 paddr;
    u64 vaddr;
};

static int axpu_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    struct resource *res;
    struct axpu_dev *axpu;
    struct device_node *np;
    int rc;
    int ret;

    res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    axpu = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(*axpu), GFP_KERNEL);
    axpu->dev = dev;
    axpu->base = devm_ioremap(dev, res->start, resource_size(res));
    res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_IRQ, 0);
    devm_request_irq(dev, res->start, axpu_irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_HIGH, "axpu_irq", axpu);
    np = of_parse_phandle(dev->of_node, "memory-region", 0);
    rc = of_address_to_resource(np, 0, res);
    axpu->paddr = res->start;
    axpu->vaddr = memremap(res->start, resource_size(res), MEMREMAP_WB);
    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, axpu);
    axpu_init(axpu);
    return sysfs_create_group(&dev->kobj, &axpu_attr_group);
}
```

and in the axpu_init function, I access it with virtual address.

```c
static void axpu_init(struct axpu_dev *axpu)
{
    printk("testing reserved memory ..\n");
    writel_relaxed(0x12345678, axpu->vaddr + 0);
    writel_relaxed(0x23456789, axpu->vaddr + 8);
    printk("read-back data = %llx, %llx\n", readl_relaxed(axpu->vaddr + 0), readl_relaxed(axpu->vaddr + 8));
}
```

When I execute it, it runs ok.

```
/ # insmod axpu.ko
axpu_probe called!
 MEM : res->start = 50000000, res->end = 5fffffff, res->name = axpu@50000000
axpu->base = ffffffc010000000
 IRQ : res->start = 15, res->end = 15, res->name = axpu@50000000
axpu_dev 50000000.axpu: Allocated reserved memory, vaddr: 0xFFFFFFC080000000, paddr: 0x90000000
writing 0x12345678 at non-mapped reserved memory 0x90000000, 0x90000008 ..
read-back data = 12345678, 23456789
```

I have put `no-map` in the reserved memory sub-node. But is accessible with virtual address.
But if I try it with physical address, it crashes as below.

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
Ignoring spurious kernel translation fault at virtual address 0000000090000000
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 27 at arch/arm64/mm/fault.c:311 __do_kernel_fault+0x108/0x150
odules linked in: axpu(+)
CPU: 0 PID: 27 Comm: insmod Not tainted 5.10.0-rc5 #548
Hardware name: ETRI ab21m (DT)
pstate: 60400009 (nZCv daif +PAN -UAO -TCO BTYPE=--)
pc : __do_kernel_fault+0x108/0x150
lr : __do_kernel_fault+0x108/0x150
```

The document says about no-map :

> no-map (optional) - empty property
> - Indicates the operating system must not create a virtual mapping
> of the region as part of its standard mapping of system memory,
> nor permit speculative access to it under any circumstances other
> than under the control of the device driver using the region.

Then what is wrong with my device tree?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your device tree. If I understand correctly, you are attempting to access a physical address directly as though it was a valid virtual address? That won't work.